# Chrome don't respect correct width when using percentage text-indent

Tags: css, google-chrome

### Playground

In the demo above, there should be 2 `.wrap` boxes, one red and below it a blue one. That should be the correct behavior.

Head-to-wall banging bug in Chrome. in Firefox, as always, everything works as spec says, but in Chrome, the percentage of the text-indent are not relative to the `.wrap` containing element width (which is encapsulated by `overflow:hidden`) but it is relative to the `clientWidth` as it would seem. any suggestions?

Comment: well at least it creates cool effect when you resize the window

Comment: I've opened a Webkit bug for this (vote it) - https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=126167

Comment: For now you will have to put a container on the outside of .wrap and make it the same width as wrap

Comment: May I ask what it is you're trying to attempt? I wonder if there'd be a less head-banging method out there that might achieve the same end result.

Comment: @michael t  - well sure there is, but I want this to work. as web developer, I expect and deserve `text-indent` to work properly by the end of 2013...

Comment: @J Max - yeah seems legit to me! :D good job!

Comment: @vsync I'd love it if things worked the way I want them, too — but let's be reasonable. As developers we also should expect to look for other alternatives when running into browser roadblocks.  But aside from that, I'm genuinely interested in what it is you're trying to attempt.

Comment: @michael t - http://codepen.io/vsync/pen/EhbLz

Comment: now i need a trick like this only for a vertical stack

Comment: Wow, curious as to why you're working so hard to re-invent the wheel on this one? There are hundreds upon hundreds of carousels out there...and ones that do basically what you're doing.

Comment: @michael t - because mine is better than them all..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed in Chrome that its taking the width as 400px instead of 200px.  So when text-indent of 100% its moving your child `div`s 200px too far.  I added `display: -webkit-box;` to your `.wrap` class which seems to work though I don't know if that's what you had in mind as a solution.